# In Windows Vista, when starting any and every program, a "bad image" error is generated

Tags: windows-vista, dll

I have a problem where any program is started under Windows Vista, the following error message is generated

> Bad Image
>   C;\PROGRA~1\Google\GOOGLE~3\GOEC62~1.DLL
>   is either not designed to run on
>   Windows or it contains an error.Try
>   installing the program again using the
>   original installation media or contact
>   your system administrator or the
>   software vendor for support.

This happens for every program started, including those that start automatically at boot time. My Google-fu is failing to solve this for me.

I have already tried an "sfc /scannow" which did find some problems, but it said that it could not correct them.

What might cause this problem? How might it be resolved?

Comment: Is it the same file path in every program, or a different one on each program? How long has this been happening?

Comment: It happens the same way on every program. It only started happening yesterday morning.

I think by eliminiation, I may have found the problem. Will post an answer if I can confirm.

Comment: Did you ever solve?  Wife has this problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been something to do with Google Toolbar, but even after uninstalling in Control Panel, the problem does not go away. I needed to completely remove the folder for it in C:\Program Files\ in order to stop the problem from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Google has inserted the DLL into [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197571) registry key.

> The AppInit_DLLs value is found in the following registry key:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
>
> All the DLLs that are specified in this value are loaded by each Microsoft Windows-based application that is running in the current log on session.